# scipy.optimize.basinhopping doesn't call accept_test. Why?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimise the output of a function using the scipy [basinhopping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) algorithm.

```
def acceptance_criteria(self,**kwargs): 
    print "kwargs "
    print kwargs

    x = kwargs["x_new"]
    beta = x[0]
    alpha = [x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6]]
    print x
    inputnow= raw_input()
    beta_gamma_pass = beta != self.gamma
    beta_zero_pass = beta >= 0.0
    alpha1_pass = alpha[0] > 0.0
    alpha2_pass = alpha[1] > 0.0
    alpha3_pass = alpha[2] > 0.0
    alpha4_pass= alpha[3] > 0.0
    alpha5_pass= alpha[4] > 0.0
    alpha6_pass= alpha[5] > 0.0
    return  beta_gamma_pass,beta_zero_pass,alpha1_pass,alpha2_pass,alpha3_pass,alpha4_pass,alpha5_pass,alpha6_pass

def variational_calculation(self):
    minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS"}

    initial_paramater_guesses = [2,1.0,1.0/2.0,1.0/3.0,1.0/4.0,1.0/5.0,1.0/6.0]
    ret = basinhopping(self.Calculate, initial_paramater_guesses, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=200, accept_test=self.acceptance_criteria)
```

I am getting problems with Nans and infs in my calculate function.
This is due to invalid parameter values being used.
I have attempted to prevent this by using acceptance criteria.
But the basinhopping routine does not call the accept_test function.
Thus the criteria remain unimplemted.

Can anyone help me out as to why basinhopping isn't calling the accept_test function?

Thanks

EDIT:
in response to @sascha's comment,
There are fractional powers of parameters, and 1/parameter terms in the function.
Not limiting the range of the allowed parameter values gives complex and inf values in this case. 
It is actually an eigenvalue problem, where I am trying to minimise the trace of the eigenvalues of a set of 18*18 matrices. 
The matrix elements depend on the 7 parameters in a complex way with dozens of non linear terms.

I have never worked on anything more complex than polynomial regression before, so I am not familiar with the algorithms or their applicability at all.
However, the function/s that I am trying to minimise are smooth as long as you avoid parameter values near poles; caused by 1/parameter and 1/(paramter^n -constant) terms.

EDIT2:
QUESTION CLARIFICATION
The question here is nothing to do with the applicability of the basinhopping algorithm.

It is why the specific implementation of it, in the 2.7 version of python and scipy, does not call the accept_test function?

Comment: Maybe because it's broken before? Does your function qualify as a valid function for this algorithm? If there are nan's and inf's, i suppose it's non-smooth? Basinhopping is not built for that!

Comment: What do you mean "broken before"?

Comment: I was not sure, what exactly your error is. You said, that some callback is not called. I don't know if your algorithm terminates with some error-state before calling this callback or not. That was what i intended to say. Also:```However, the function/s that I am trying to minimise are smooth as long as you avoid parameter values near poles``` sounds pretty nonsmooth to me :-). I'm not that familiar with eigenvalue-problems, but some of these are trouble in regards to numerical problems. I think you should stick to some more simple local-optimizer first and check if these are working correctly

Comment: The problem is that basinhopping does not call the accept_test function at all.
Several iterations can occur, then parameter values that need to be avoided are chosen. They are chosen despite the accept_test function, which would return False for those values. Then nonvalid values are encoutered.

If basinhopping ran the accept_test function for the parameters, and then only proceeded if the parameters were valid, then there would be no problem.

The accept_test function is not being called, despite it being specified that it should do so.

Comment: The ```accept_test``` you want to use is used as some kind of Metropolis criterion. Even if your implementation would call this function (to reject invalid values) it will possibly result in losing all the theoretical-guarantees of the basinhopping-algorithm. Again: it's designed for smooth-functions.

Comment: Yes, and over the parameter range I am trying to specify the function is smooth.

Comment: Read some introduction about nonlinear-optimization. What you want to do / your approach is doomed.

Comment: Why is this approach "doomed"?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why your example doesn't work, but here's a similar but minimal example where it does call the accept_test, maybe you can spot the difference

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

class MyClass:
    def Calculate(self, x):
        return np.dot(x, x)

    def acceptance_criteria(self, **kwargs):
        print("in accept test")
        return True

    def run(self):
        minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS"}

        initial_paramater_guesses = [2,1.0,1.0/2.0,1.0/3.0,1.0/4.0,1.0/5.0,1.0/6.0]
        ret = basinhopping(self.Calculate,
                           initial_paramater_guesses,
                           minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                           niter=200,
                           accept_test=self.acceptance_criteria)

my_class = MyClass()
my_class = my_class.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but it still shows up on Googling this question.

I was having the same issue, so I ran a test by modifying the code here a bit and adding a counter. My code minimizes 5 variables, but requires all values to be greater than 0.5

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
n = 0

def acceptance_criteria(**kwargs):
    print("in accept test")
    X = kwargs['x_new']
    for x in X:
        if x < .5:
            print('False!')
            return False
    return True

def f(x):
    global n
    print(n)
    n += 1
    return (x[0]**2-np.sin(x[1])*4+np.cos(x[2]**2)+np.sin(x[3]*5.0)-(x[4]**2 -3*x[4]**3))**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = basinhopping(f,[.5]*5,accept_test=acceptance_criteria)
```

It took about 100 iterations before entering the acceptance_criteria function.

If you are optimizing a function that takes a long time to run (as I was), then you might just need to give it more time to enter into the acceptance_test.